# Consulta con subconsulta para Eloquent de Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Laravel + VueJS. Entre otros apartados, el proyecto disponde de una tabla "contactos" dónde se almacenan los correos de consulta que envían los usuarios por el formulario de contacto de la web.

Esta es la estructura actual de la tabla "contactos":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna "msg_origen" sirve para indicar si el registro se refiere a un mensaje original o un mensaje de repuesta a otro mensaje. De tal forma que si es un mensaje original o inicial de un usuario, en esta columna se guarda un valor de 0, y si se trata de un mensaje de respuesta hacia un mensaje original, entonces, se almacena el ID del mensaje original.

Lo que desearía sacar con la consulta / subconsulta sería el listado de todos los mensajes junto con el total de respuestas que tenga cada mensaje de la tabla.
Espero algo de ayuda pues hace tiempo que no tengo práctica en este tipo de consultas SQL

He probado algo así por el SQL del phpMyAdmin, pero no me ha dado el resultado deseado (igual me falta algún GROUP BY o algo parecido):

```
SELECT id, nombre, correo, (SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM contactos 
WHERE msg_origen = id) as total_respuestas 
FROM contactos
```

Y luego, como comento en el título de esta pregunta, me gustaría saber como adecuar el SQL deseado al formato Eloquent de Laravel. Gracias. Saludos.

Comment: podrias crear una columna virtual,  que sea msg_origen+id, eso determina cual es respuesta y cal es preguna, luego harias la consulta agrupando por ese campo virtual que creaste

Comment: @EderDanielValcarcelVanegas ... ¿no podrías ampliar tu comentario en una respuesta más amplia en la que indicar como llevar a cabo todo, es decir, cómo crear ese supuesto campo virtual y cómo realizar esa consulta agrupando por dicho campo virtual? Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien **msg_origen** es tu llave foránea. Puedes hacerlo con subconsultas pero te recomiendo que lo hagas directo con un join

```
$msn = Contacto::join('mensajes', 'mensajes.id', '=', 'contacto.msg_origen')
->where('msg_origen', $id_que_buscas)->get();
```

Esto te regresara el join de las dos tablas en una sola consulta. Si utilizas subconsultas le metes mas sobre carga a la base de datos.

Otra opción es crear la relación en el modelo de contactos y en el modelo de mensajes.

Comment: No, disculpa, en ningún momento comento que haya más de una tabla. Todo el esquema pertenece a la misma tabla "contactos". La columna "msg_origen" es de esa tabla y no es que haga referencia a otra tabla externa. Si fuera así, ya lo haría como dices a través de relaciones entre modelos. Pero no es así, todas las columnas son de la tabla "contactos". De ahí que no me se ocurra como plantear la consulta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No está muy clara la pregunta, pero, si entendí bien, podrías separarlo en dos consultas y te quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$queryResult = DB::table('contactos')
    ->select('id', 'nombre', 'correo')
    ->get();

foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
    $resultado = DB::table('contactos')
        ->where('msg_origen', $row->id)
        ->count();

    $dato->row = $resultado;
}

return $queryResult;
```